# How to Make Tab index work for Radio Buttons which are in same group?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, controls, radio-button

I have a scenario like this

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="userActiveYesRadioButton" GroupName="activeGroup" Text="Yes"
       runat="server" TabIndex="4" />&nbsp;
<asp:RadioButton ID="userActiveNoRadioButton" GroupName="activeGroup" Text="No"
       runat="server" TabIndex="5" />
```

Since these radio buttons are in same group , tab index is not working. Is is possible to make tabindex work in this scenario ?
If I remove the group , they dont remain mutually exclusive.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alternate,
Remove GroupName attribute and use javascript to make radio buttons mutually exclusive.

For Example

```
function toggle(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "Radio1") {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Radio2').checked = false;
    }
    else if (obj.value == "Radio2") {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Radio1').checked = false;
    }
}
```

Call 'toggle(this)' on onClick event of radio buttons.

Note: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_' is added to control id because of Content Place holder.

Comment: Instead of "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Radio2" you could write "<%=Radio2.ClientID%>", this way you will will get the correct client id regardless of how many parent, Content Place holders you have and and if you are building a user control, you can use in more than one master page :)

Comment: @FahadHussain this solution works for me too , but once its focus, and when I hit enter button its not getting checked :(

Comment: @HassanMokdad this solution works for me too , but once its focus, and when I hit enter button its not getting checked :(